# How can I do a partial integration test (phpunit)?

Tags: php, unit-testing, integration-testing, nextcloud

I am working on an extension (app) of nextcloud (which is based on Symfony). I have a helper class to extract data from the request that is passed by the HTTP server to PHP. A much-reduced one could be something like this (to get the point here):

```
<?php
namespace OCA\Cookbook\Helpers;

class RequestHelper {
  public function getJson(){
    if($_SERVER['Request_Method' === 'PUT'){ // Notice the typos, should be REQUEST_METHOD
      $raw = file_get_content('php://input');
      return json_decode($raw, true);
    } else { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

Now I want to test this code. Of course, I can do some unit testing and mock the `$_SERVER` variable. Potentially I would have to extarct the `file_get_content` into its own method and do a partial mock of that class. I get that. The question is: How much is this test worth?

If I just mimick the behavior of that class (white box testing) in my test cases I might even copy and paste the typo I intentionally included here. As this code is an MWE, real code might get more complex and should be compatible with different HTTP servers (like apache, nginx, lighttpd etc).

So, ideally, I would like to do some automated testing in my CI process that uses a real HTTP server with different versions/programs to see if the integration is working correctly. Welcome to integration testing.

I could now run the nextcloud server with my extension included in a test environment and test some real API endpoints. This is more like functional testing as everything is tested (server, NC core, my code and the DB):

```
phpunit  <---> HTTP server  <--->  nextcloud core  <--->  extension code  <--->  DB
                                                           ^
                                                           |
                                                           +-->  RequestHelper
```

Apart from speed, I have to carefully take into account to test all possible paths through the class `RequestHelper` (device under test, DUT). This seems a bit brittle to me in the long run.

All I could think of is adding a simple endpoint only for testing the functionality of the DUT, something like a pure echo endpoint or so. For the production use, I do not feel comfortable having something like this laying around.

I am therefore looking for an integration test with a partial mock of the app (mocking the business logic + DB) to test the route between the HTTP server and my DUT. In other words, I want to test the integration of the HTTP server, nextcloud core, my controller, and the DUT above without any business logic of my app.

How can I realize such test cases?

---

**Edit 1**
As I found from the comments the problem statement was not so obviously clear, I try to explain a bit at the cost of the simplicity of the use-case.

There is the nextcloud core that can be seen as a framework from the perspective of the app. So, there can be controller classes that can be used as targets for URL/API endpoints. So for example `/apps/cookbook/recipe/15` with a `GET` method will fetch the recipe with id `15`. Similarly, with `PUT` there can be a JSON uploaded to update that recipe.

So, inside the corresponding controller the structure is like

```php
class RecipeController extends Controller {
  /* Here the PUT /apps/cookbook/recipe/{id} endpoint will be routed */
  public function update($id){
    $json = $this->requestHelper->getJson(); // Call to helper

    // Here comes the business logic
    // aka calls to other classes that will save and update the state
    // and perform the DB operation
    $this->service->doSomething($json);

    // Return an answer if the operation terminated successfully
    return JsonResponse(['state'=>'ok'], 200);
  }
}
```

I want to test the `getJson()` method against different servers. Here I want to mock at least the `$this->service->doSomething($json)` to be a no-op. Ideally, I would like to *spy* into the resulting `$json` variable to test that exactly.

No doubt, in my test class it would be something like

```php
class TestResponseHandler extends TestCase {
  public function setUp() { /* Set up the http deamon as system service */}
  public testGetJson() {
    // Creat Guzzle client
    $client = new Client([
      'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8080/apps/cookbook',
    ]);
    // Run the API call
    $headers = ...;
    $body = ...;
    $response = $client->put('recipe/15', 'PUT', $headers, $body);

    // Check the response body
    // ....
  }
}
```

Now, I have two code interpreters running: Once, there is the one (A) that runs phpunit (and makes the HTTP request). Second, there is the one (B) associated with the HTTP server listening on `localhost:8080`.

As the code above with the call to `getJson()` is running inside a PHP interpreter (B) **outside the phpunit instance** I cannot mock directly as far as I understand. I would have to change the main app's code if I am not mistaken.

Of course, I could provide (more or less) useful data in the test function and let the `service->doSomething()` method do its job but then I am no longer testing only a subset of functions but I am doing functional or system testing. Also, this makes it harder to generate well-aimed test cases if all these side-effects need to be taken into account.

Comment: What do you mean by a "partial mock"? Why not use Guzzle and mock the API part away properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I just updated the last paragraph a bit. I am not concerned about how I can trigger a request (here guzzle's aim is) but the other side of the request.  I want to make a request that does merely nothing serious during testing, just like an echo server.

Comment: @NicoHaase What do you mean by *mock the API part away properly*?

Comment: Exactly that: write a test that does not use `Guzzle` to perform proper API requests, but injects a mocked Guzzle instance instead

Comment: Something like https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html - which can also be done on other similar client libraries

Comment: @NicoHaase I edited the question once more as it seems we are talking about different issues here. I am still saying that my problem is the server-side and not the `Guzzle` side of the problem. `Guzzle` might be a nice tool but it initializes the HTTP request. I need to mock on the HTTP receiver side.

Comment: Sorry for getting that wrong - but, if you are using something based on Symfony, why do you use `$_SERVER` instead of their `Request` object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227845/discussion-between-christian-wolf-and-nico-haase).